# Custom Replacement Function in VBA for Excel

Tags: excel, vba, replace

I'd like to create a custom function for Excel performing a character replacement inside a string.

Assume in excel cell A1 I have the string
*[abc_123|def_456]: example*
There is a pattern in this string given by the squared brackets.
As output I'd like to have in cell B1 the string *[abc|def]*, thus erasing all the numbers and the underscore within the squared brackets.

If cell A1 contains string
*another example*
I'd like to return as output in B1 the value *None*.

I wrote the following VBA lines to be inserted in a new module. Can you please review them to check if it accomplishes the task?

```
Function Output(AdGroupName)
ClosingBracket = InStrRev(AdGroupName, "]")
Dim TMP As String
Dim Output As String
TMP = Left(AdGroupName, ClosingBracket)
TMP = Replace(TMP, "0", "")
TMP = Replace(TMP, "1", "")
TMP = Replace(TMP, "2", "")
TMP = Replace(TMP, "3", "")
TMP = Replace(TMP, "4", "")
TMP = Replace(TMP, "5", "")
TMP = Replace(TMP, "6", "")
TMP = Replace(TMP, "7", "")
TMP = Replace(TMP, "8", "")
TMP = Replace(TMP, "9", "")
Output = Replace(TMP, "_", "")
End Function
```

Comment: Your Q is not clear.  Give some example inputs and the corresponding required outputs. Edit these into your Q.

Comment: `Can you please review them to check if it accomplishes the task?` I think you can answer this better since you're the one writing and testing the code. What we can do is if you have specific issues with it, we can help you fix it or somehow improve it.

Comment: Did you try your code? Maybe we can help you to solve your problem, for code review, maybe you can try [Code Review](http://codereview.stackexchange.com/)

Answer (score 0):

So with the little you gave us looking at your code you just forgot to make the function = the output.

Try this

```
Public Function Tester(AGN) As String

ClosingBracket = InStrRev(AGN, "]")
TMP = Left(AGN, ClosingBracket)
TMP = Replace(TMP, "0", "")
TMP = Replace(TMP, "1", "")
TMP = Replace(TMP, "2", "")
TMP = Replace(TMP, "3", "")
TMP = Replace(TMP, "4", "")
TMP = Replace(TMP, "5", "")
TMP = Replace(TMP, "6", "")
TMP = Replace(TMP, "7", "")
TMP = Replace(TMP, "8", "")
TMP = Replace(TMP, "9", "")
Output = Replace(TMP, "_", "")

Tester = Output
End Function
```

I tested this with the example you gave us and the output was [abc|def]